# Regex to require some words and not accept a word

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

```
<iframe.+?((width="320")).+?(?!height=".+")src="https?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})"[^>]+?><\/iframe>
```

I need to match a youtube iframe with width="320" but no height. It still returns true even if I put height.
Please guide me.

Comment: ① *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — Which language, JavaScript?

Comment: ② *NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead.*

Comment: sorry, this is for php. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead anchored to start:

```
(?!.*height="[^"]+")iframe.+?width="320".+?src="https?://www.youtube.com/embed/([\w-]{11})"[^>]+?></iframe>
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to match <iframe width="320" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/12345678901" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: What language are you using? I removed the escapes for all the slashes because they aren't required. If you're using JavaScript you'll probably need to wrap the entire expression is slashes and escape slashes.

Comment: php ^(?!.*height="[^"]+")iframe.+?width="320".+?src="https?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/([\w-]{11})"[^>]+?><\/iframe>

Comment: turns out i just need to remove the carrot at the start. Thanks man